# Why does my created Amazon IAM user get "We can not find an account with that email address" when trying to log in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In the [Amazon IAM Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home), I created a new IAM user, and assigned that user permissions and a password.

However, when an attempt to log in with that new IAM user is made via the Amazon AWS login page at https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home, an error occurs:

```
There was a problem

We can not find an account with that email address
```

Why can't my IAM user log in successfully?

Answer (score 11):

Amazon IAM users can't log in through the main Amazon AWS login page.

Instead, they need to use a custom login URL which is displayed at the top of your IAM Dashboard page.  That link is labeled "IAM users sign-in link", and is of the form:

```
https://AWS-account-ID-or-alias.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
```

Using that account-specific IAM login form, the user should be able to log in successfully.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_sign-in.html